# How can I extract URLs from the source code of a webpage?

Tags: bash, mp3

I am trying to setup a stream for some scanners I have found on Broadcastify. The problem is that the URLs they use are dynamic and only the same for a few hours a time. I would like to create a shell script that can simply scan the page from which the stream is accessed (which does have a static URL) and return the current URL of the stream, which can then be fed to the audio player.

For instance, right now the following stream at https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/feed/30185/web has a stream at http://audio12.broadcastify.com/kq2ydfr1jz98shw.mp3

However, that stream link will only work for a short period of time. I need an MP3 stream like the one above.

[image]

I only have minor experience with shell scripting, so I'm wondering what the best approach would be here. Specifically, my first problem is if I simply "View page source" and search for "mp3", there are no results. I can only find the URL by inspecting element (F12 developer tools) and, in Chrome for instance, going to Application → Frames → Media. I thought I could do a "view frame source" on the audio player in the past but that option isn't there now.

I imagine I could use grep if I was able to CURL the source code, but I'm not sure what I would need to CURL here, if that makes sense.

**UPDATE**

Thanks mk12 for the insight. Based off that, here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl "https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/feed/$1/web" | grep webAuth > /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt
pta=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt | sed -i 's/$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { "webAuth": "//g' /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt`
pta=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt | sed -i 's/" }});//g' /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt`
auth=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastifyauth$1.txt`
echo $auth

curl "https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/webpl.php?feedId=$1" --request POST --header "webAuth: $auth" --data 't=14' >/var/tmp/broadcastify$1.txt

pta=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.txt | grep -o 'http://[^"]*' > /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.b.txt`
pta=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.b.txt`
echo $pta
#pta=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.txt | sed -n '/<audio/s/^.*<audio width="300px" id="mePlayer_$1" src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' > /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.b.txt`
#ptb=`cat /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.b.txt`
#echo $ptb
```

Here is its output:

```
root@na01:/etc/asterisk/scripts/music# ./broadcastify.sh 30185
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9175  100  9175    0     0  51843      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 52130
74f440ad812f0cc2192ab782e27608cc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   946    0   942  100     4   3851     16 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3844
http://relay.broadcastify.com/b94hfrp5k1s0tvy.mp3?xan=DCJP4HvtwMoXdH9HvtwMJ5vv342DfleDptcoX3dH9H48vtwMJ
```

Works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mp3 URL is not present in the original HTML document — it's added to the DOM later by JavaScript code. That's why you can't find it in "View page source," but you can with "Inspect element."

If you run `curl https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/feed/30185/web`, you will see the following somewhere in the middle:

```html
<div id="fp" width="300px"></div>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { "webAuth": "74f440ad812f0cc2192ab782e27608cc" }});
    $('#fp').load('/listen/webpl.php?feedId=30185',{t:14});
</script>
```

Note in particular that it loads content (using [jQuery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) into the initially empty `<div id="fp">` just above. When you use "Inspect element" to find the audio player, you'll find it gets placed inside that div.

Before trying to reproduce this request with curl, I looked in the Network tab of the developer tools to see what the browser did. Filtering for "listen," I found the `webpl.php` request. Here is the relevant information from the "Headers" tab:

- URL: `https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/webpl.php?feedId=30185`
- Request

  - POST /listen/webpl.php HTTP/1.1
  - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  - webAuth: 74f440ad812f0cc2192ab782e27608cc
- Query String Parameters

  - feedId: 30185
- Request Data

  - MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  - t: 14

Let's reproduce this request with curl:

```sh
curl 'https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/webpl.php?feedId=30185' \
  --request POST \
  --header 'webAuth: 74f440ad812f0cc2192ab782e27608cc' \
  --data 't=14'
```

Here's the result:

```html
<script src="/scripts/me_4.2.9/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/me_4.2.9/mediaelementplayer.min.css"/>
<audio width="300px" id="mePlayer_30185" src="http://relay.broadcastify.com/9wzfd3hrpyctvqx.mp3?xan=DCJP4HvtwMoXdH9HvtwMJ5vv342DfleDptcoX3dH9H48vtwMJ" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"
       autoplay="true">
</audio>
<script>
    $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        features: ['playpause', 'current', 'volume'],
        error: function () {
            alert("Feed has disconnected from the server.  This could be due to a power outage, network connection problem, or server problem.  Click OK to restart the player.  If the player fails to connect then the feed might be down for an extended timeframe.");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
<br />
<div class="c">If the feed does not automatically play, click or touch the play icon in the player above.</div>
```

There's your mp3 link, in the `src` attribute of the `<audio>` tag. If we try to get it:

```
$ curl http://relay.broadcastify.com/9wzfd3hrpyctvqx.mp3?xan=DCJP4HvtwMoXdH9HvtwMJ5vv342DfleDptcoX3dH9H48vtwMJ
Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to http://audio13.broadcastify.com/9wzfd3hrpyctvqx.mp3?nocache=2623053&xan=DCJP4HvtwMoXdH9HvtwMJ5vv342DfleDptcoX3dH9H48vtwMJ
```

If you try to access that URL (or the original one with `-L`, instructing curl to follow redirects), the mp3 stream will start printing to your terminal as a bunch of nonsense characters.

So, your shell script should hit the `/listen/webpl.php` endpoint instead of trying to scrape the web player HTML page. Or perhaps just scrape the page to first get a webAuth token.

### Update

In response to your update with the shell script, here is a simplified script that does the same thing and also strips the "Moved Temporarily" prefix to just get the audio url. Note that there's no need to use a temporary file, and the `$(...)` syntax is preferred over the `` `...` `` syntax:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# I always start my scripts with this. See https://sipb.mit.edu/doc/safe-shell/
set -eufo pipefail

auth=$(curl -s "https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/feed/$1/web" \
    | grep webAuth \
    | head -n 1 \
    | sed 's/^.*"webAuth": "//;s/".*$//')

relay_url=$(curl -s "https://www.broadcastify.com/listen/webpl.php?feedId=$1" \
    -H "webAuth: $auth" -d 't=14' \
    | grep -o 'http://[^"]*')

audio_url=$(curl -s "$relay_url" | cut -d' ' -f5)

echo "$audio_url"
```

Comment: I was able to get a shell script working based off your answer, thanks much!

Comment: One last thing... although the URL returned from the script does play if I copy it into a browser, it does not play in the stream application I am using. I am thinking this is probably because of the redirect at the end. So, I think I need to resolve the redirect in the shell script, since my player won't/can't do this. How do I do this? I have tried a few different recommended ways but none work. I can do the curl statement you have at the end, but how do I capture the url after "Redirecting to" so that I can use it?

Comment: Neither of these methods work: curl -i $ptb -L | egrep -A 10 '301 Moved Permanently|302 Found' | grep 'Location' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | tail -1 >/var/tmp/broadcastify$1.txt

wget -S $ptb 2>&1 | grep ^Location: > /var/tmp/broadcastify$1.c.txt

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for your help again!